Is there a way how to disable annotations in generated code in IntelliJ?
when i try to use code generation functionality in intellij it adds some annotations to the code. Is there a way how to disable it?
For example, if I write a variable name without any type like:
modified = collection.stream()...

and then press Alt+Enter on the variable name I get the 'Create local variable' context menu. See the screenshot:


Now if i hit enter then this lovely and readable piece of code is generated:
@org.getbrains.annotations.NotNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.Unmodifiable List<@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull StateNode> modified = collections.stream()...

screenshot:


As you can see it can not even be compiled, since there is no such package in the code (org.jetbrains)
So the question is - is there a way how i can tell IntelliJ to just create the List<StateNode> (which is correct type), without trying to add a lot of unreadable code that breaks the compilation?
Thanks

Post text, not images

updated the question with the code as text

Please give a minimum code example, including imports
